# Connecting Next.js API with Next.js client on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

there is monorepo for development where are two folders - `client`, `api`. Developing on localhost is working very fine. But a problem, of course, is on AWS. My whole setting is in `next.config.js` which is

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:slug*',
        destination: `${process.env.API_URL}/api/:slug*`
      },
    ] 
  }
```

but this is not working on AWS Amplify. I suspect that should be more setting in Rewrites and redirects or AWS Cloudfront, but I don`t have any clue. Do you have some experience with that?

Error:
`403 Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on `client` folder, where wasn't directory `pages/api` with any file and AWS CloudFront couldn't detect the directory for some internal settings. Look at the image bellow - There wasn't `Path pattern - 'api/*'`, now it is. :)

[image: There wasnt Path pattern api/*`]

Comment: How did you access the CF distribution associated with the Amplify app? I am only seeing the custom created distributions in the CF dashboard.